# Try...Catch...Finally in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, try-catch

In VB.NET, if you return a value from the `Catch`, will the `Finally` code still execute?

For instance (I've generalized this code a bit):

```
Try
    response = Client.doRequest()
Catch ex As Exception
    'Request threw an error - Fatal failure.
    InsertErrorLog(ex)
    Return False
Finally
    DisposeClient()
End Try
```

I need to ensure that `DisposeClient()` is executed all of the time. Because I am returning out of the `Catch`, will the `Finally` still be executed?

Comment: Move the caret to Finally and press F1.  You can't avoid falling in the pit of success: "Control passes to the Finally block just before it passes out of the Try…Catch structure. This is true even if an exception occurs anywhere inside the Try structure".  Only ask for help if F1 can't get the job done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`Finally`** block is always executed, regardless of code execution going to **`Catch`** block or not.

Refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

---

Try it, using this code:

```
Dim Temp As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Temp = "A"

    MessageBox.Show(Test())
    MessageBox.Show(Temp)
End Sub

Private Function Test() As String
    Try
        Temp = "B"
        Throw New Exception()
        Temp = "C"

        Return "Try"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Temp = "D"
        Return "Catch"
    Finally
        Temp = "E"
    End Try

    Temp = "F"
    Return "End"
End Function
```

It displays message:

```
Catch
```

and then

```
E
```

This means, **`Finally`** block is always executed even the function do return at **`Catch`** block.

Answer (score 1):

On closer inspection to the Microsoft MSDN docs, I notice:

> Control is passed to the **Finally** block regardless of how the
>   **Try**...**Catch** block exits.
>
> The code in a **Finally** block runs even if your code encounters a **Return**
>   statement in a **Try** or **Catch** block.
>
> Control does not pass from a **Try** or **Catch** block to the corresponding
>   **Finally** block in the following cases:
>
> - An **End** Statement is encountered in the **Try** or **Catch** block.
> - A **StackOverflowException** is thrown in the **Try** or **Catch** block.

In short, yes - the **Finally** is always executed in *most* cases.